# Woocommerce "woocommerce_product_get_price" issue

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, hook

The filter "woocommerce_product_get_price" to show a custom price works but casually I have discovered that this filter is triggered five times in single product page and six times in the archive product page. This I have checked including a var_damp in the following way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'get_ws_price', 10, 2);

function get_ws_price($price, $product){

    var_dump('HI!');

    $price = 99.99;

    return $price;

}
```

This is a problem for me, I use this filter to perform complex code and is repeating them many times.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to modify the price of the product with another hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce also has this problem which it solves by caching. It uses the WordPress get_transient() and set_transient() to save a version in the WordPress database. This allows the calculation to be used over multiple requests. Further, the calculation is saved in a global object so that within a single request the calculation can be retrieved from an in memory object.

WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT::read_price_data() in file '...\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\data-stores\class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php' is a good example of this technique.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Comment: I am really sorry guys, I have the same issue, but I really can't get how this answers the OP's question. I am missing something, how to use this piece of information ?

Answer (score 0):

You could choose to not use the filter and write your own function to replace `get_price_html()`.  With the new function you can overwrite your WooCommerce templates such as the single product page `woocommerce\templates\single-product\price.php` and replace any calls to this function with your own custom function.  This way it will only be called once.

Comment: I have tried to modify the template but I can not access the properties of "WC_Product_Simple Object", they are all protected. My situation is a bit special but it should be easy to solve. The products are loaded in the WP db without price, when a user logs the product views they call a web service to download the price based on the user's properties.

For this reason the hook "woocommerce_product_get_price" is very useful because it modifies the product object and I can process it without problems in the cart.

Comment: You can access the global $post variable and from that you can create your own WC_Product_Simple object from the $post->ID.